# JavaScript (Rhino) conditioning

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, rhino

i have a this piece of code that generates a number

```
num = scriptletInput;

var s = num+"";
while (s.length < 3) s = "0" + s;

// To set the response of the operation: 
scriptletResponse = "Success"; 

// To set the result of the operation 
scriptletResult = s;
```

In that case generated number will start by "001"

Now i would love to include a condition, there will be a variable existing, and "if" the content of the variable is equal to the string "image", start generating numbers above 100, but if the variable does not contain the string "image" generate number starting with 001. How can i do that?

**

### Post edit:

**

Succeeded to some extent with the following code
from the global context i receive a variable called imageType (which could contain string "image" or different) 
And here to evaluate the input of imageType variable i did:

```
num = scriptletInput;
imageVar = imageType;

var s = num+"";
while (s.length < 3) {
if (imageVar === "image") {
s = "1" + s;
} else{
s = "0" + s;
}
}

// To set the response of the operation: 
scriptletResponse = "Success"; 

// To set the result of the operation 
scriptletResult = s;
```

This is generating number 111 if the variable imageType is equal to string "image", or generates number 001 if that same variable does not contain the string. I would have loved to start generating numbers by 100, instead of 111, but it's a good start for me at least to learn things :)

Comment: Please specify precisely what values you expect in `scriptletInput`; e.g. for an input of "1" the output should be "001", for an input of "image-" the output should be, what about an input of "100" - what's the output for that?

Comment: the script will take as an input numbers from 1 to 224. It will generate the number and then i will check if the number already exists, and if not use it.

Comment: So how will the content of the variable be "image"?

Comment: image will be another variable that i want to include and this my question how can i do that :)

Comment: So you want a function like `function doIt(scriptletInput, anImage)`?

Comment: I want this same script to extend in such a way, that if there is variable equal to text string "image", the number that the script produces should start by 100

Comment: if variable == image generate numbers above 100 up to 224
if variable != image generate number from 001 and above, could be up to 224 actually

Comment: This variable will come from the global context, i only have to evaluate it in this piece of code...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, then I think you're looking for this (that is, this will start with `100` if `imageVar` equals "image").

```
importPackage(java.lang);
function getNum(num, imageVar) {
  if (imageVar === "image") {
    if (num == 0) {
      num = 100;
    } else if (num < 100) {
      num += 100;
    }
  }
  var s = num+"";
  while (s.length < 3) {
    s = "0" + s;
  }
  return s;
}

var iv = "test";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  System.out.println("Loop1: " + getNum(i, iv));
}
iv = "image";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  System.out.println("Loop2: " + getNum(i, iv));
}
```

Outputs

```
Loop1: 000
Loop1: 001
Loop1: 002
Loop1: 003
Loop1: 004
Loop1: 005
Loop1: 006
Loop1: 007
Loop1: 008
Loop1: 009
Loop2: 100
Loop2: 101
Loop2: 102
Loop2: 103
Loop2: 104
Loop2: 105
Loop2: 106
Loop2: 107
Loop2: 108
Loop2: 109
```

Comment: Elliott your output looks pretty much like what i was expecting, i promise to test that tomorrow, because i need to go now for a meeting. Thanks man! :)